# Bundle many LESS files into a single LESS file

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gulp, less, gulp-less

I'm making a library containing some generic UI components, some kind of Bootstrap. Suppose I have the following LESS files structure:

```
button.less
checkbox.less
index.less
variables.less
```

Each component style file has `@import "variables.less";`. Index file imports all components files. Now I would like to distribute library.less and variables.less files into a package.

How do I bundle the index file? I used to concatenate all the files and remove repeated `@import "variables";` line using regexps, maybe there is a Less API for doing this.

Comment: No, Less has no facilities for producing less files. So for this kind of stuff you're on your own. By the way, there's no reason to remove redundant imports (aside from making the the "package" more readable) since any subsequent imports of the same file have no effect anyway (see [the docs](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-once)).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `less-bundle` https://www.npmjs.com/package/less-bundle

```
// variables.less
@red: #ff0000;
@grey: #cccccc;

// button.less
@import 'variables.less';
.btn-danger {
     background: @color;
}

// checkbox.less
@import 'variables.less';
input[type='checkbox'] {
   background: @grey;
}

// index.less
@import 'button.less';
@import 'checkbox.less';
```

Here is main code to do that.

```
// bundler.js
const path = require('path')
const bundle = require('less-bundle');
const srcFile = path.join(__dirname, './index.less');

bundle({
  src: srcFile,
  dest: path.join(__dirname, './bundle.less')
}, function (err, data) {
  console.log('Error Bundle', err, data);
});
```

Run bundler.js using command `node bundler.js` and it will create a `bundle.less` file containing all styles.

```
// bundle.less
@red: #ff0000;
@grey: #cccccc;

.btn-danger {
     background: @color;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
   background: @grey;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer and addressed my exact use case.